# Red dot indicator appears even when I'm banned from reviewing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, top-bar

I am seeing the red dot indicator for SO's review queues even though I've been temporarily banned from them. Can we remove the indicator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the release of our [new review suspension notification system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions), users who are in a review suspension will no longer see the indicator when there are items to review during the duration of their suspension. They will see the indicator light up one time to draw their attention to the suspension but after that notice has been seen, the indicator will remain dark.

If you run into any issues with this, please let us know!