# On user profile page, the review ban link needs updating to the changed review ban history event parameter

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools, review-suspension

*This is a bug report about a moderator-only feature.*

---

Recently, review bans were renamed to review suspensions.

The user history event was renamed to "User has been suspended from reviewing", with the URL parameter `/users/history/123456?type=User+has+been+suspended+from+reviewing`.

However on user profiles (for mods), if the user is currently review suspended, the link is still the old version which does not filter the history events since the old parameter no longer exists: `/users/history/123456?type=User+has+been+banned+from+review`

> [image: screenshot of incorrect link]

Comment: This is [tag:status-completed]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351300/