# Could we get a more informative dropdown for when you don't have any review queues due to daily votes?

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar, wording

Currently, if a user has used up all their votes for the day (regardless of whether they did it in the review queues or not), the First Post and Late Answer queues will be hidden from their dropdown. If the user then doesn't have access to any other review queues, they get the message:

> There are no review queues available to you

Which does a poor job of explaining *why*. Previously, this was most often due to review bans (now suspensions), but [that's no longer the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/681403).

Would it be possible to change this to something that is more informative? I suggest something like:

> You've used all your votes for the day, so there are no review queues available to you at the moment.